# Where can I find XML Data Binding Wizard in Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, ide

It seems I have removed XML Data Binding Wizard from Delphi XE IDE, because I can't see it in th IDE.[image: All options in Delpih IDE]

Which BPL-library should I install for turning on this wizard again?

Comment: You haven't specified which Delphi version you're using.

Comment: Delphi XE professional edition

Comment: According to the [`Delphi XE Feature Matrix`](http://www.embarcadero.com.pl/produkty/delphi/dxe/delphi-features-matrix.pdf) this feature (BizSnap) is only present in Architect and  Enterprise editions of Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi Professional only includes the XML Schema Binding Wizard (which creates a object and interface structure based on the schema), not the Data Binding Wizard (which supports transformations to datasets).

Comment: Only, which BPL-library should I install for turning on this wizard back?

Answer (score 3):

You have to have an open project before it's available (of any kind).

- **File->New->VCL Forms Application**
- **File->New->Other, choose Delphi Projects->XML**
- Double-click the **XML Data Binding** item in the right pane

[image: IDE New Item Dialog image]

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't this options, my configuration is described above

Comment: Your image above is exactly what I see if I open the **File->New->Other** dialog **without an active project**. When I have an open project, the one I've shown in my answer appears instead. Please do a **File->Close All**, and then start with the steps I've described (bbeginning with **File->New->VCL Forms Application**.

Comment: I have just tried, result is same. I haven't seen any XML wizards - http://screencast.com/t/9kGk7isXOePa